# Getting java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out during AWS CodeBuild

Tags: java, jar, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

During acceptance testing in AWS CodeBuild we are able to request a .jar into the pipeline, but the command invoking the .jar fails to execute (URL's & IP's modified in this example, for obsfuscation purposes):

```
[Container] 2020/07/08 14:53:37 Running command java -jar qa-jenkins-cli.jar -s https://example.com/jenkins/ -noCertificateCheck build RUN-l1-Regression -s -v -p ReasonForRun="AWS pipeline run" -p slavepool="DI" -p HOST_VALUES="127.0.0.1 sp.l1.example.com"
Skipping HTTPS certificate checks altogether. Note that this is not secure at all.
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
    at hudson.cli.CLI.connectViaCliPort(CLI.java:210)
    at hudson.cli.CLI.<init>(CLI.java:128)
    at hudson.cli.CLIConnectionFactory.connect(CLIConnectionFactory.java:72)
    at hudson.cli.CLI._main(CLI.java:479)
    at hudson.cli.CLI.main(CLI.java:390)
    Suppressed: java.io.EOFException: unexpected stream termination
        at hudson.remoting.ChannelBuilder.negotiate(ChannelBuilder.java:331)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.<init>(Channel.java:422)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.<init>(Channel.java:401)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.<init>(Channel.java:397)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.<init>(Channel.java:386)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.<init>(Channel.java:378)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.<init>(Channel.java:354)
        at hudson.cli.CLI.connectViaHttp(CLI.java:159)
        at hudson.cli.CLI.<init>(CLI.java:132)
        ... 3 more

[Container] 2020/07/08 14:54:01 Command did not exit successfully java -jar qa-jenkins-cli.jar -s https://example.com/jenkins/ -noCertificateCheck build RUN-l1-Regression -s -v -p ReasonForRun="AWS pipeline run" -p slavepool="DI" -p HOST_VALUES="127.0.0.1 sp.l1.example.com" exit status 255
[Container] 2020/07/08 14:54:01 Phase complete: PRE_BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2020/07/08 14:54:01 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: java -jar qa-jenkins-cli.jar -s https://example.com/jenkins/ -noCertificateCheck build RUN-l1-Regression -s -v -p ReasonForRun="AWS pipeline run" -p slavepool="DI" -p HOST_VALUES="127.0.0.1 sp.l1.example.com". Reason: exit status 255
```

Here is the *app-test-buildspec.yml* (the `wget` works):

```
# builld spec version.  keep at 0.2
# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec-ref-versions
version: 0.2

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      #- echo "Installing jq (JSON parser)..."
      #- yum install -y jq gettext
      - echo "deploy_phase=${deploy_phase} developer_prefix=${developer_prefix} environment=${environment} account_id=${account_id} account_alias=${account_alias}"
      - $(cat version.json | jq -j '"export app_name=\(.app_name) app_version=\(.app_version) s3_version=\(.s3_version)"')
      - echo "app_name=${app_name} app_version=${app_version} s3_version=${s3_version} developer_prefix=${developer_prefix} environment=${environment}"
      - $(cat app-deploy.json | jq -j '"export UseFargate=\(.Parameters.UseFargate)"')
      - echo "UseFargate=${UseFargate}"
      - wget https://example.com/jenkins/jenkins-cli.jar -O qa-jenkins-cli.jar
      - java -jar qa-jenkins-cli.jar -s https://example.com/jenkins/ -noCertificateCheck build RUN-l1-Regression -s -v -p ReasonForRun="AWS pipeline run" -p slavepool="DI" -p HOST_VALUES="127.0.0.1 sp.l1.example.com"
  build:
    commands:
      - pip install boto3 pytest
      - pytest -o log_cli=true -o log_cli_level=INFO -v tests/test_ecs_cluster.py

artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
```

We have DNS mirroring set up so that certain AWS processes have access to on-prem services, such as the test suite we're trying to run here. The tests are being run in the VPC because of the mirroring. We know that the mirroring is working because we can execute the `wget` that retrieve the .jar file. We cannot see this call in the flow logs anywhere.

Does anyone have any insight on what may be going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found that the test .jar file was trying to execute tests on another on-prem device which had firewall settings causing the command request to drop at that firewall with nothing other than a time out response.

Lessons learned - if you're going to run hybrid systems using a combination of AWS and on-prem resources you must know exactly what resources are required and where they are located. In a large scale system documentation of processes may be less than exact or non-existent. You must have excellent tools to track down the point at which the issue occurs (WireShark was the lifesaver here) so you can understand how to remediate.